# Can you help me to solve this error?

Tags: magento-1.9, error

**Fatal error:** Class 'Helper_Data' not found in app\Mage.php

**Fatal error:** Class 'Mage_Parcelamento_Helper_Data' not found in

> C:\wamp64\www\magento\app\Mage.php on line 547

**Error log:**

> Warning: include(Mage\Parcelamento\Helper\Data.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line
>   94

I did what you said, but it's still with the same error.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B66I9AyUOaAnS21VMmNFSlEwSEk

Answer (score 1):

Your extension is calling helper data from extension `Bizcommerce_Parcelamento` So you need to integrate this extension too.

If you check this class

```
class FLB_Cielo_Block_Form_Cc extends Mage_Payment_Block_Form_Cc {

    /** @var Bizcommerce_Parcelamento_Helper_Data */
    private $_parcelamento = null;

    protected function _construct() {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_parcelamento = Mage::helper('parcelamento');
        $this->setTemplate('cielo/form/cc.phtml');
        $this->setModuleName('Mage_Payment');
    }

public function getParcelas() {
...

        $this->_parcelamento->numparcelas = $maxParcelas;
        $this->_parcelamento->parcelaMinima = $valorMinimo;
        $this->_parcelamento->juros = $taxaJuros;
        $this->_parcelamento->tipoJuros = $tipoJuros;
        $this->_parcelamento->numParcelasSemJuros = $parcelasSemJuros;
        $this->_parcelamento->descontoPrimeiraParcela = $descontoPrimeiraParcela;
        $parcelamento = $this->_parcelamento->getParcelamentosPossiveis($total);

}
```

Data are getting called from this helper data which is not found so you are getting the error `Mage_Parcelamento_Helper_Data` not found.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I really don't understand, I have to put this code where? In config.xml ?

Comment: You dont have to put this code. I have shown you this code so you can understand why you were getting error.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But I don't know what I have to do, I'm no programmer :/

Comment: give some details of your extension

Comment: Well, it's a Cielo module for automatic payments